# I made a query to show images through keywords. Why does it show multiple of the same images?

Tags: php, image, phpmyadmin

First off, I made a search query to help me find images depending on keywords. I started with `'SELECT * FROM images WHERE image LIKE "%'.$search.'%"'` and that worked fine. Then I did `'SELECT * FROM images,images_2 WHERE images.image LIKE "%'.$search.'%"'` and everything did not work quite alright. I started to get multiple of the same images and each table has different images. May anyone please help me with this error?

```
<?php
    //You could always do it seperately
    if (isset($_POST['submit-search'])){
        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","****","photos");
        $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['search']);
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM images WHERE images.image LIKE "%'.$search.'%"';
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $queryResult = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        echo "<p>Found ".$queryResult." quote(s)</p>";

        if ($queryResult > 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                echo "<a href='uploads/".$row['image'].">";
                echo "<img id='img_div' src='uploads/".$row['image']."'/>";
                echo "</a>";
            }

        } else{
            echo "There are no quotes matching your search.";
        }
    }?>
```

Comment: If they show up multiple times in the table that could be it. Try selecting only the columns you want, not star, and use DISTINCT on one of the columns that should be unique to each image

Comment: You're open to SQL injection, you should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM images, images_2 WHERE images.image LIKE "%'.$search.'%"
```

You're joining images and images_2 when you use `images, images_2`, but there's no criteria for the join, so you'll get every combination of rows from both tables.

It looks like you're trying to get images from two different image tables, so probably what you need to do instead is `UNION` rather than `JOIN`. When you join the two tables, it combines records from both of them into the same row, but with union, it's more like selecting all the matching rows from both tables.

Without knowing the rest of the structure of your tables, it's difficult to say how to write the union query, though. Assuming the two tables are structurally identical, it would be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM images WHERE images.image LIKE "%'.$search.'%"
UNION
SELECT * FROM images_2 WHERE images2.image LIKE "%'.$search.'%"
```

If the two tables *aren't* structurally identical, select only the corresponding column(s) from each table rather than using `*`.

Comment: To the OP: This answer is simpler than the answer I've provided below, and is the one that you should use. The `union` is the same idea, except that this answer queries the images/images_2 tables directly, rather than having to put them into a derived table to query against. This answer is the better way to do it, but I'll leave my answer up because knowing how to query unioned tables may help you with something else in the future.

Comment: Thank you @RobbieToyota and @Don'tPanic! I would also like to ask. If I wanted to add another query like that, would I keep the same format add another `UNION`?

Comment: @Jane.S.Wilson yes, that's right. However, it makes me wonder about your database design a bit. If this search is something you'll be doing frequently, it might be worth trying to put all your images into one table. If there are multiple tables that all have images, you can create foreign keys to the images table rather than storing image data in many different tables. (But I don't know all the details, so I'm just guessing.)

Comment: I have like different categories depending on images. For instance, one image is for happiness and the other is for motivation. And I have a happy table and motivate table all in the same database.

Comment: It's probably more complex than what we should try to discuss in the comments here. I just wanted to let you know that there is another way to do it if you end up having trouble doing it this way.

Comment: Yeah. Thank you again, @Don'tPanic!

Comment: @Jane.S.Wilson Just throwing this out there: rather than separate tables for different categories, you may want to have a single images table and add a column for "category". Then you can do things like `select * from images where category='happy'`, instead of `select * from happy_images`. It may make your life easier, and will be more efficient than unioning multiple queries.

Answer (score 1):

With your second query, where you specify two tables, you're getting duplicates because you're not specifying any criteria for your images_2 table. Thus, it's returning everything from images_2.

What you'll want to do is `union` the two tables together into one `derived` table, and then query against that table. If you need further explanation on what is happening in this query, let me know. I've formatted the query to make it clearer to read:

```
select
    image
from
    (
        select image from images
        union
        select image from images_2
    )
    as t -- Give this derived table a name
where
    image LIKE '%{$search}%'
```

On a side note, look into using prepared statements. Injecting a user-supplied value (eg from $_POST or $_GET) directly into a query is dangerous; and escaping the string won't protect you from everything.

Comment: FYI: See Don't Panic's answer; it is the simpler and (far) more efficient method to solve this problem.